# Creating a custom views access plugin

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a custom views access plugin, so I can perform my conditions for accessing a view.

I read several tutorials and checked the source of existing modules, but I must be coding/doing something wrong because this never works properly.

Here's the code:

File: `sample.module`:

```
function sample_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
  );
}
```

File: `sample.views.inc`:

```
function sample_views_plugins() {
  $plugins = array(
    'access' => array(
      'test' => array(
        'title' => t('Custom access check'),
        'help' => t('This is a custom access plugin.'),
        'handler' => 'sample_access_plugin',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $plugins;
}

class sample_access_plugin extends views_plugin_access {
  function summary_title() {
    return t('Custom acces plugin');
  }
  function access($account) {
    return sample_access($account);
  }
  function get_access_callback() {
    return array('sample_access', array());
  }
}

function sample_access($account = NULL) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

I can see the access plugin in views, and I can select it. However, no matter what I do, the access to the view will always be forbidden (access denied). There are no messages in the error log.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the sample.views.inc file does not get loaded during the access-check (as the registry already cached the information which callback it needs to execute).

So you can just move sample_access() to the file sample.module and the callback works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will check this and keep you posted!

Comment: THANKS A LOT! That was it - it's working properly now :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted on the [documentation for hook_views_plugins()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7):

> **handler (required)**: The name of the file containing the class describing the handler, which must also be the name of the handler's class.

So you should put `sample_access_plugin` class in a file called `sample_access_plugin.inc`, and note also:

> **path**: Path to the handler. Only required if the handler is not placed in the same folder as the .module file or in the subfolder 'views'.

I believe that `sample_access_plugin.inc` also needs to be listed in the `files[]` section of your module's info file in order for the class to be autoloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the message; the access plugin is already listed in the `files[]` section. The solution was what Nebel54 said - the access callback function needs to be loaded always, meaning it should either be in the `.module` file or some other file that is always present.